# Modify values captured by reference in lambda of std::future

Tags: c++, lambda, future

Can someone explain to me why modification of values captured by reference in the lambda of a std::future does not produce the result that I expect? See code:

```
const int runs{ 1000 };
for (int run = 0; run < runs; ++run)
{
    const int num{ 4 };
    std::vector<bool> res(num, false);
    std::vector<std::future<void>> futs(num);
    for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i)
    {
        futs[i] = std::async(std::launch::async, [&res, i]
        {
            res[i] = true;
        });
    }
    for (auto& fut : futs) fut.wait();
    for (auto v : res) // I expect all values of res to be set to true.
    {
        if (!v) std::cerr << "Bad!!!\n"; // But this happens!
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but please, don't use `(v != true)`... just write `(!v)`

Comment: You cannot modify multiple items of `vector<bool>` concurrently, because according to [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool) it may lead to undefined behaviour: *Does not guarantee that different elements in the same container can be modified concurrently by different threads*. You can replace `vector<bool>` by `vector<int>`, then everything will work fine.

Comment: @rafix07 Why not write this as an answer!?

Comment: Thanks @rafix07! Now I understand why

Comment: @user3134182 also see [Second point of draft](https://eel.is/c++draft/container.requirements.dataraces#2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have data races which lead to undefined behaviour.
Different items of `vector<bool>` should not be modified concurrently by different threads.

You can read about it [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool)

> Does not guarantee that different elements in the same container can
>   be modified concurrently by different threads.

or [here](https://eel.is/c++draft/container.requirements.dataraces#2)

> Notwithstanding [res.on.data.races], implementations are required to
>   avoid data races when the contents of the contained object in
>   different elements in the same container, excepting vector, are
>   modified concurrently.